# Issue with Publishing ASP.NET Core (with .net framework) vs 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Getting below issue while publishing asp.net core(with .net framework) application
from visual studio or with cmd prompt `dotnet publish`

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll' is denied.

Comment: Are you running VS2015 in admin mode?

Comment: No luck !!!!.. There is a post in github...
https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3419

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to publish to temp folder. You can publish to any other folder in C or D drives using the command  `dotnet publish -o C:\Publish `  You may not get the access denied error in this case.

Comment: Make sure the directory folder you choose to contain your published project is not set to Read Only

Answer (score 0):

I had that one because the files of my project were under source control (perforce in my case). Checking app.config out did the job for me, I just keep it checked out, never submitting it.

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Two suggestions then. 1- when you have app.config check out and before trying to recompile again, delete manually every product of the compilation (bin folder most of the time) 2- Can you check with [processexplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if you have a process holding this DLL: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll